# Angular js - simple loop on json object

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi there i'm trying prnting a simple json object to a div:

```
<div ng-repeat=" i in config.app_genres.genres">
    {{  i }}
</div>
```

and

```
 config.app_genres = {
 "genres":["asd","ips"]
}
```

what's wrong with this?

Also how can i `log config.app_genres` in a view?

Comment: It wud be better if u post full code including html and javascript and most important thing is to check console error in browser, if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hqWYaL9ET05iiaWLDmmU?p=preview).

As for logging `config.app_genres` in the view, not sure what you mean, care to elaborate?

Comment: so need i strictly a controller ? can't i iterate on a global rootScope object ?

Comment: of course you need a controller, how can you access any scope without a controller? even if you want to use `$rootScope` you need a controller for that.

Comment: just cause i'm setting $rootScope params  to have them ready where needed

Comment: there is no way to print out data without a controller in a loop?? :O

Comment: controllers are what glue your view to some data, i can't imagine how you'd tell your view what to print without controllers.